# Spark API completeness - Scala vs. Java vs. Python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My guess is that the Scala API is feature-complete. However, I cannot see in the documentation any indicator that a given class member is available only in some APIs.

Let's take `SparkContext.getRDDStorageInfo` an example:

- [Scala API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@getRDDStorageInfo:Array[org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo]) - present
- [Java API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#getRDDStorageInfo()) - present
- [Python API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext) - I cannot find it

Is there a matrix that shows the availability of the different members in the APIs?

**UPDATE:**

Both Scala and Java documentation contains an annotation *Developer API* for `SparkContext.getRDDStorageInfo` - as the link in the comment explains it means it is a *a lower-level, unstable API intended for developers that might change or be removed in minor versions of Spark* ([source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/common/tags/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/annotation/DeveloperApi.java#L23-L25)). However, I don't know if that also means *not available in Python API*.